How is `text-overflow: ellipsis` working here, when the required conditions aren't meeting?
I know that for text-overflow: ellipsis  to work, a few conditions must be met:

The element must have a set width or max-width.
The overflow property must be set to hidden, scroll, auto, or clip.
The white-space property must be set to nowrap.

I have not used white-space:nowrap; then how is text-overflow: ellipsis still working?
Here's my code


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>doubt</title>
    <style>
        .box {
            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 60px;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="box">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo voluptatibus nam, quos error voluptate temporibus
        voluptates, optio eum hic vero eligendi nobis non officia maiores, enim nemo nihil illo. Natus sapiente odio
        esse est.
    </div>
</body>

</html>




I don't know what to do, I'm just confused.

What is the result you are you expecting ? nothing seems wrong according to your CSS rules.

i wasn't expecting text-overflow:ellipsis to work cause I didn't include white-space:nowrap;. I just wanted to ask why it's still showing ellipsis.

This statement is incorrect:

The white-space property must be set to nowrap.

This is not actually true. You might find this stated on some websites, but it does not agree with the CSS specification. Here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#text-overflow

Text can overflow for example when it is prevented from wrapping (e.g. due to white-space: nowrap or a single word is too long to fit).

The behaviour you are seeing is completely correct.

Is it also because white-space is set to normal by default for Block elements like div?

@RishabhGaur not really, as there is no other white-space setting that would make this act differently, at least not without doing something entirely different, anyway. But instead of asking about what IS happening, here, if you tell me what you fully WANT to happen in your situation, I can try to help with that - as I am not totally sure what you are even trying to achieve here!

@RishabhGaur Though I should add, if you simply want to break the words up instead of having the "..." or cutting them off, you can use word-wrap: break-word;
